# my code is not displaying a string stored in a variable

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class guessGame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String ansOne;
        String ansTwo;
        String result="";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("TWO QUESTIONS!");
        System.out.println("Think of an object and I'll try to guess it");
        System.out.println("Qusetion 1) Is it a animal,vegetable or mineral?  ");
        ansOne = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Qusetion 2) Is it bigger than a bread box");
        ansTwo = sc.next();

        if(ansOne == "animal" && ansTwo == "yes"){
            result = "Squirrel";
        }
        else if( ansOne == "animal" && ansTwo == "no"){
            result = "moose";
        }
            else if( ansOne == "Vegetable" && ansTwo == "Yes"){
            result = "carrot";
        }
            else if( ansOne == "Vegetable" && ansTwo == "no"){
            result = "Watermelon";
        }
            else if( ansOne == "mineral" && ansTwo == "Yes"){
            result = "Paper clip";
        }
            else if( ansOne == "mineral" && ansTwo == "no"){
            result = "Camero";
        }
        System.out.println("My guess is that You are thinking of a " +result);
        System.out.println("I would ask you if I'm right,but I don't actually care...");  
    }  
}
```

In the above code,I want to display the result. But its not been
displayed, I am getting the following output:

> TWO QUESTIONS! 
>   Think of an object and I'll try to guess it 
>   Qusetion 1) Is it a animal,vegetable or mineral?
>   vegetable 
>   Qusetion 2) Is it bigger than a bread box 
>   yes 
>   My guess is that You are thinking of a
>   I would ask you if I'm right,but I don't actually care...

Comment: You compare Strings with `equals()` and not `==`

Comment: if none of your `if else-if` is true `result` will be an empty string,also use `equals()` for string comparisons

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use sc.nextLine() rather than sc.next().  Additionally use equals() rather than '=='

Comment: An additional comment: you can use "moose".equals(ansOne) to check for equality in a null-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare your strings with equals ()

E.g. String1.equals("Lalala");

You wil get unexpected results if you use == for comperision.